# Accessing private function in included php file

Tags: php, class

I currently have two php class files and I'm working on accessing functions across them. Currently, in the secondClass.php file, I'm able to call a function in firstClass.php successfully and that class then calls another in the same firstClass.php file which is expected to return a result

I can access the function successfully, but when I check if the firstClass function `isLoaded` is true or access it I get an error because it's a private function

How can I get the returned object from this private function in firstClass.php?

firstClass.php

```php
private function loadData($id){
  return $this->isLoaded();    
}

private function isLoaded(){

  $var = 123;

  return $var;
}
```

secondClass.php

```php
public function getResult($id){
  $firstC = new firstClass();

    $result = 'ABC';
    $newResult = $firstC->loadData($result);

    if($firstC->isloaded){
        echo('we are good');
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. You must expose it through a public method.

Comment: Also, you're not actually calling the method here: `if($firstC->isloaded){`. What's happening here is an attempt to access a property called `isloaded`. You need to add the parentheses to call the method: `if($firstC->isLoaded()){`.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you. I guess I'll change it to public then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a property to the first class that is public.

```
public isLoaded = false;
```

Then you could change that value using your method. And I think technically your method name there is flirting with being a verb vs being a noun. You could update the existing isLoaded method to be something like checkIsLoaded which sets the public property to true or false.

```
public isLoaded = false;

private function loadData($id){
  return $this->isLoaded();    
}

private function checkIsLoaded(){
    
    $var = 123;

    $this->isLoaded = $var;
}
```

Now you can access it with the same format you have:

```
$firstC->isloaded;
```